# How could I rearrange the lines in this file and print them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my text file named "words.txt"

```
7 dog
3 moose
6 apple
2 dinosaur
```

This is what I have so far:

```
file = open('words.txt','r')
for lines in file:
    number, word = lines.split()
    numbers = int(number)
```

So basically I've split the number from the words and made the numbers into integers, I'm not sure if this is possible but is there a way to rearrange these words by lowest number to highest number? I'm clueless at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> lines = [l.rstrip('\n') for l in open('words.txt')]
>>> print('\n'.join(sorted(lines, key=lambda l:int(l.split()[0]))))
2 dinosaur
3 moose
6 apple
7 dog
```

Comment: Nice, but it relies on the last line being newline-terminated. If it isn't, you'll get `2 dinosaur3 moose` as the first line of your output.